# "Reboot and Select proper Boot device" (Harddisk Ubuntu installation with UNetbootin)

Tags: 14.04, unetbootin

This is my first time setting up and OS myself. I want to delete my Windows OS and install Ubuntu instead.

As I don't have a USB stick available, I used the UNetbootin to create a bootable Live USB drive.

The installation was perfect because I could interact with the Ubuntu OS, install Chrome, etc.

Then after reloading the system, I'm getting this message: "Reboot and Select proper Boot device"

Please advice how to fix this considering I used UNetbootin to install Ubuntu.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Please edit your question to include the make/model of the computer (laptop?) that you're running as this will help in troubleshooting this issue. Also include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. Thanks